# Como melhorar meu layout em HTML?

Tags: html

Senhores(as), preciso fazer os seguintes retângulos abaixo em html, conseguem me instruir qual seria a melhor opção indicada?[image: Painel de metas por pessoa]

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    
    background-size: cover;
}
.container {
    width: 380px;
    height: 160px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.container div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.rel, .acu {
    grid-column: span 2;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="row1">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="marca">Felipe Cardoso</div> 
        <div class="meta">Meta</div>
        <div class="rel">Realizado</div>
        <div class="acu">100%</div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

O mais próximo que eu conseguir chegar foi nesse trecho de código que estou utilizando, mas querem no formato da imagem em anexo, se puderem me indicar qual a função ideal para se utilizar nesse caso, agradeço.

Comment: Está usando algum framework?

Comment: Estou desenvolvendo a partir do JSP @JoãoPedroSchmitz

Comment: Me refiro ao CSS

Comment: @JoãoPedroSchmitz, não estou utilizando nenhum Framework como por exemplo o Bootstrap, estou fazendo direto.

Comment: @JoãoPedroSchmitz mas eu tenho a biblioteca do Bootstrap toda instalada com o Node.js, etc, porém ainda não uso, você teria alguma função lá dentro que se encaixaria nesse meu projeto?

Comment: Gabriel como esse layout funciona de forma linear da esquerda para direita e com um ítem após o outro acho que o flex seria melhor que o grid, até pq repare que o quinto item está centralizado no meio da tela, com o Grid vc não consegue centralizar o :last-child dessa forma. Essa resposta vai te ajudar a entender o que estou dizendo. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/327488/flexbox-css-grid/327518#327518 Vou ver se faço um exempo desse layout pra vc. Para esse layout ainda não vejo vantagem em usar Bootstrap... a não ser que ele já estivesse instalado em uso em outras partes do sistema

Comment: Show @hugocsl, vou verificar esse tópico que você me passou.

Comment: @hugocsl se puder me encaminhar um exemplo do flex com meu projeto eu agradeço.

Comment: Da uma olha lá na resposta, qq dúvida comenta lá que te ajudo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para esse caso em particular, como falei no comentário, eu te indicaria o `flexbox` e não o `grid`, pois como vc pode ver nessa pergunta o Grid não vai te dar a possibilidade de alinha o último item no centro do *container* [FlexBox + CSS GRID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/327488/flexbox-css-grid/327518#327518)

Agora sobre o modelo que montei, o principal é vc usar o `flex-grow`, para que cada uma das partes do `.box` tenha seu tamanho proporcional a outra, no caso eu usei valores 3, 2, e 1, isso significa que a entre as partes existe uma proporção entre as larguras, que pode variar dependendo do tamanho do conteúdo dentro da célula, pois o flex é flexível com relação a isso.

Já na *label* "sobre" o `.box` eu usei um *pseudo elemento* `::after` no `.p2` e com no `content:" "` dele eu coloquei o *texto* que precisa.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.jumbo {
 background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/600/300);
 background-size: cover;
}
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
.box {
  width: calc(50% - 2rem);
  height: 2rem;
  margin: 1.5em 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}
.p1, .p2, .p3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: red;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.p1 {
  flex-grow: 3;
}
.p2 {
  flex-grow: 2;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
.p3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.p2::after {
  content: "texto";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5em;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .box {
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbo">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="box">
   <div class="p1">
   grow 3
   </div>
   <div class="p2">
   grow 2
   </div>
   <div class="p3">
   grow 1
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
   <div class="p1">
   texto1
   </div>
   <div class="p2">
   texto2
   </div>
   <div class="p3">
   texto3
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
   <div class="p1">
   texto1
   </div>
   <div class="p2">
   texto2
   </div>
   <div class="p3">
   texto3
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

Para fazer a parte *responsive* vc pode usar o `@media`, veja como deve ficar por ai, em telas menores de 580px cada `.box` deve ocupar 100% do *container*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: basicamente era disso que eu precisava, show de bola. Vou tocar o meu projeto com essa base que você me passou, caso surjam novas dúvidas eu faço novas perguntas, obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @GabrielPaixãoJustino demoro, se tiver alguma dúvida ou quiser algum esclarecimento é só falar.

Comment: sabe como consigo adicionar um espaçamento em  entre elas ? Por exemplo na minha imagem, a primeira linha de box tem um espaçamento para a segunda, estou tentando espaçar mas está deformando.

Comment: @GabrielPaixãoJustino funciona assim, o que vc adicionar de `margin` vc tem que adicionar no `calc()` do `width`. Exemplo se vc aumentar a margem entre os box para `3rem`,no `calc` vc tem que colocar `calc(100% - 6rem)` - É `6rem` pq é `3rem` de margin na direita e `3rem` na esquerda. Então temos 100% menos as margens da direita e esquerda? Qq coisa fala ai!

Comment: poderia me informar onde consigo inserir uma imagem de fundo ? Preciso inserir essa imagem de fundo em meu projeto, e essas divs ficarão "vivas" em meu painel, estou inserindo no .container, mas a imagem não está ficando correta.

Comment: @GabrielPaixãoJustino qual o problema que a imagem está apresentando? Vc está usando ela como uma `<img>` dentro do container ou como `background-image` do container?

Comment: @hugocls, estou utilizando como  `background-image`.

Comment: @hugocls, inseri na primeira pergunta a imagem com o problema que está ocorrendo.

Comment: @GabrielPaixãoJustino cara eu não entendi muito aquela imagem que vc postou... parece que tem um elemento por cima do outro... não sei o que vc arrumou ai rss. Mas eu atualizei o código da resposta acima, coloquei por fora do container uma outra div, nessa div eu coloquei um background-image que engloba todo o container. Olha ai como ficou.

Comment: Excelente, obrigado @hugocsl.