# centralizando div dinamicamente

Tags: html, css

Bom tenho o seguinte código que estou montando:

```css
.pg {
  width: 100%;
}

.pg>.produto {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="pg">





  <div class="produto">
    x
  </div>


  <div class="produto">
    x
  </div>
  <div class="produto">
    x
  </div>

  <div class="produto">
    x
  </div>

  <div class="produto">
    x
  </div>

  <div class="produto">
    x
  </div>

  <div class="produto">
    x
  </div>

  <div class="produto">
    x
  </div>

  <div class="produto">
    x
  </div>

  <div class="produto">
    x
  </div>






</div>
```

Bom o código esta lá, a medida que redimensiona a página as div vão caindo para a linha de baixo. Porém quero evitar um espaço em brando do lado direito, ou seja quando não couber outra `div produto` as div devem ser centralizadas. Evitando o espaço vazio.

Segue a foto do espaço vazio:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem uma forma com flex, mas a última fileira de itens sempre vai ficar centraliza...

Veja no exemplo como fica, deixei uma borada e coloquei a largura do `container` em 90% apenas para dar um "espaço em branco" nas laterais e vc ver que centralizou.

```css
.pg {
  /* width: 100%; */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    overflow: auto;
    justify-content: center;
}

.pg>.produto {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="pg">

    <div class="produto">
      x
    </div>

    <div class="produto">
      x
    </div>
    <div class="produto">
      x
    </div>

    <div class="produto">
      x
    </div>

    <div class="produto">
      x
    </div>

    <div class="produto">
      x
    </div>

    <div class="produto">
      x
    </div>

    <div class="produto">
      x
    </div>

    <div class="produto">
      x
    </div>

    <div class="produto">
      x
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: A minha resposta é mais curta!! Rá!

Comment: @fernandosavio é que eu coloquei umas perfumarias a mais rss. Agora o esquema é deixar os itens da última linha a esquerda, sem centralizar... ;)

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria. Obrigado

Comment: @HugoBorges tranquilo xará! Se te interessar no assinto aqui tem outras resposta com problemas similares, onde com display:grid o último item fica a esquerda. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/327488/flexbox-css-grid/327518#327518 e aqui tb outras opções de grid limitando 4 por linha https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/324963/como-colocar-um-limite-de-4-imagens-por-linha/324976#324976

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar CSS Flex para isso.

Basta que você diga que `.pg` é um conteiner flex e configure as propriedades [`flex-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) e [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

[Este guia](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) é bem prático para usar como *cheatsheet*.

```css
.pg {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.pg > .produto {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="pg">
  <div class="produto">x</div>
  <div class="produto">x</div>
  <div class="produto">x</div>
  <div class="produto">x</div>
  <div class="produto">x</div>
</div>
```